# Imgur Clone: error "param missing or value is empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm re-doing an assignment that is a clone of Imgur.

I tried adding a picture to the database with an artist, title and URL: but now I have an error stating my param are missing or the value is empty. I've searched and searched and I'm not getting any closer.

Here is my pictures_controller.rb:

```
class PicturesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @picture = Picture.all
    end

    def show
        @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    end


    def new
        @picture = Picture.new
    end

    def create
        @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
        if @picture.save
            redirect_to pictures_url
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
        @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])

        if @picture.update_attributes(picture_params)
            redirect_to "/pictures/#{@picture.id}"
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
        @picture.destroy
        redirect_to pictures_url
    end

    private
    def picture_params
        params.require(:picture).permit(:artist, :title, :url)
    end

end
```

I really appreciate your help, all. I'm completely stumped! And it's probably something really small, as usual :-\ Thank you.

Comment: what are you receiving in params?

Comment: don't use hard-coded url like this one: `redirect_to "/pictures/#{@picture.id}"` use the URL helpers instead: `redirect_to picture_path(@picture)`

Comment: Small point, but Rails generally likes you to use correct pluralisation. So in index: `@pictures = Picture.all`

Comment: Can we see the view for 'new' and the params that are being sent to the 'create' action?

Comment: Guys, I fixed this yesterday and completely forgot to update this. Thanks all!

Comment: I also made the changes that MrYoshiji and A Fader Darkly suggested. Thank you again!